# CSS and Images Keeping centered while resizing

Tags: css, image, resize

I was looking at this website.  The hero image as it is re sized the css (I believe) is overflowing the image as well as keeping it centered.  The link is below.  I tried to check out the nuts and bolts of the site to see if I could figure it out.  But couldn't...  any help would be awesome.  I would like to recreate this but don't know how.

Thanks - It's a German site. Css is bilingual :)

[Example of picture](http://www.tellssoehne.ch/)

Comment: i can't see any heros there , what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `background-size:cover;` and `background-position:center center;` to do this in CSS:

```
div{
  background-image:url(image.png);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
```

[**More on `background-size` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> cover: This keyword specifies that the background image should be
>   scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions
>   are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.

[**More on `background-position` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)

> The background-position CSS property sets the initial position,
>   relative to the background

Comment: So there's no need for an overflow so that the image when re sized can go past the margins like in the above example?